# How to set environment variables in app created with create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I created an app with `create-react-app` and I'd like to configure some envs in JS files. Where should I put these files if I want them to be executed just after server initializing?

I've tried adding `index.js` to the root folder and creating `server/config.js` file, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your purpose here is to check the application environment in the front end then no need set any .env file, you can just set global variables before running the script you need inside package.json file like that:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=LOCAL react-scripts start"
   "build": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=PRODUCTION react-scripts build"
}
```

so whenever you want to work in your local environment you will run `npm start` and this will set `REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT` variable to `LOCAL` value.

and the same work when you want to run the application in production you run `npm run build` script and that will set the variable  `REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT` to `PRODUCTION` value

you can use the same variables in your js config file to get the current environment like that:

`export const isDevelopment = REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT === 'LOCAL';
export const isProduction = REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT === 'PRODUCTION';`

Comment: It gives me `'REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I wonder why it works for others

Answer (score 2):

Create a .env file in root directory of your app. Prefix every environment variable with the string REACT_APP_varNameHere.
Find examples here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Hm, to be honest, my real purpose is setting different `HTTP_PROXY` value for production and development environment. I wanted to do it by writing conditional statements in JS. Can I achieve that using .env file?